# How to create a custom chrono clock

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I'm creating a timeline UI control, and time on this timeline always starts at zero, like a stopwatch. I thought of using std::chrono::steady_clock to keep the start and end time on the scale, however, it feels wrong to have a clock-time here, like '10am march 2017' has nothing to do with the beginning of the scale.

Should I/can I create a custom clock that starts time at '0'?

Comment: You _can_ create a custom clock that starts at 0.  It is difficult to say whether you should or not because I don't know how your time_points are to be used.  Do they need to be stable across runs of the program, or exported/imported to other processes?  Do they need nanosecond precision?  Second precision?  Minute precision?  Would simply storing `now()` from an existing clock and subtracting that off of future times be sufficient?  Do you have code example use cases you can show us?

Comment: thanks for responding howard, love your cppcon chrono talks btw. Storing a steady_clock time_point would work for me. To answer your questions, the time_points  are internal to the process so no worries there, but I do need nanosecond precision.

Comment: I think I'll just use a normal stead_clock. Out of interest how can I define a type that is like steady_clock but with epoch at 0? I would like to experiment on it :)

Answer (score 8):

Here is an example custom chrono clock that is based on `steady_clock` and counts time since the first time it is called (approximately):

```
#include "chrono_io.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

struct MyClock
{
    using duration   = std::chrono::steady_clock::duration;
    using rep        = duration::rep;
    using period     = duration::period;
    using time_point = std::chrono::time_point<MyClock>;
    static constexpr bool is_steady = true;

    static time_point now() noexcept
    {
        using namespace std::chrono;
        static auto epoch = steady_clock::now();
        return time_point{steady_clock::now() - epoch};
    }
};

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    std::cout << MyClock::now().time_since_epoch() << '\n';
    std::cout << MyClock::now().time_since_epoch() << '\n';
    std::cout << MyClock::now().time_since_epoch() << '\n';
    std::cout << MyClock::now().time_since_epoch() << '\n';
}
```

One just needs to define the nested types `duration`, `rep` and `period` which it can just steal from `steady_clock`, and then create it's own `time_point`.  One should not use `steady_clock`'s `time_point` because the epoch of `MyClock` and `steady_clock` are different, and you don't want to accidentally mix those two `time_point`'s in arithmetic.

Since `MyClock` is based on `steady_clock`, it `is_steady`.

And the `now()` function stores the current time `epoch` in a `static` (evaluated the first time it is called), and then just finds the time since the `epoch` each time it is called.  This subtraction creates a `duration`, which can be used to construct a `MyClock::time_point`.

I'm using [`"chrono_io.h"`](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/chrono_io.html) just because I'm lazy in my formatting.  You don't need that header to create your own custom clock.  This does nothing but make it easier to print out durations.

This program just output for me:

```
1618ns
82680ns
86277ns
88425ns
```