# Provide custom implementation of std::chrono::steady_clock::now()

Tags: c++, g++, c++-chrono, bare-metal

I'm looking to use some of the C++11 chrono library features in a bare-metal environment (on an automotive PowerPC microcontroller, using GCC ~4.9).

I'd like to write some portable/multi-arch (to x64 Linux/Windows) drivers and middleware that need to calculate some delays.

There is an implementation of std::chrono::steady_clock, but it always returns -1000000000. I have code to configure a suitable hardware timer to provide a monotonic microsecond count.

Is it possible to substitute my timekeeping functions for whatever GCC is calling? I'd like to potentially hook different HW timers for different applications too.

I've written my own steady_clock look-alike shim that I can do custom child classes for on each platform, but it would be nice if I could make the standard library work instead of forcing everyone to use this shim, it also complicates the APIs for code modules since it isn't a single global static class (you have to pass in a pointer to the clock object).

Comment: You could alias the type to `namespace project { using steady_clock = my_shim_steady_clock; }`. Then write the code to use your alias and set a different alias for different platforms?

Comment: That isn't too bad, at least then there is a single place to change it out w/ preprocessor definitions or different arch-specific header file inclusion.

Comment: I would write your look-alike shim to look exactly like a chrono clock: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42812008/576911